# website search with Yii

Tags: php, yii

I'm new one to Yii Framework, and i want to integrate the "Website search" with Yii. Can anyone please suggest the best and simplest way of integrating this in my site. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simplest way-Learn how to do it

Comment: please tell me the best extension for this integration.

Comment: have you tried searching for extensions in yii's extensions directory?

Comment: yes. I tried with Zend Lucene extensions. But it makes my site becomes too slow. And i didn't get the result with this(i don't know where i have the mistake).

Comment: I recomended to use Sphinx (http://sphinxsearch.com/) search engine. It has API so it is easy to entegrate to Yii

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use [Zend Lucene](http://framework.zend.com/manual/fr/zend.search.lucene.html), there is a [wiki explaining how to do it in Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/248/adding-search-to-yii-blog-example-using-zend-lucene/) .
You have to be aware that with a lot of content (hundred thousands of entries in you DB) [Zend Lucene](http://framework.zend.com/manual/fr/zend.search.lucene.html) is going to be really slow performing a query.

If you can install [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) on your server (java is required) there is an [extension to handle this search engine](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/solr/).